# Regex get value between braces inclusive the braces with split

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a Regex for a split in Javascript that will split a string on every position where there are braces with text inside {t}.

The problem I have is the Regex expression. At the moment I have a Regex expression that matches the braces {}, but when I split the string on these braces, the braces will have been removed by the split function.

So imagine I have a string: "My name is {name} and I am {years} old". On that String I will use the expression below:

```
const splitted = value.split(/[{}]+/g); // Value is "My name is {name} and I am {years} old"
console.log(splitted);
```

Above console.log shows

```
["My name is ,", "name", " and I am ", "years", " old"]
```

But I want

```
["My name is ,", "{name}", " and I am ", "{years}", " old"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group:

```js
const s = "My name is {name} and I am {years} old";

var arr = s.split(/({[^}]*})/g);

console.log(arr);
```

`{[^}]*}` matches a substring that starts with `{` and ends with `}` and by putting a capture group around this pattern we ensure that this group is part of the `split` result.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still learning Regex and have a difficult time with it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use lazy Quantifier for this.

```js
const s = "My name is {name} and I am {years} old";

var arr = s.split(/({[^]*?})/g);

console.log(arr);
```

Lazy quantifier `*?` gives you the shortest match that fits the regex.